# CRM 2011 Report importation in batch

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a CRM 3.0 that I migrated to CRM 2011. Now, I want to import all the reports from CRM 3.0 to CRM 2011.

I know I can download the report as a RDL file and create a new report from existing file in CRM 2011. The problem with this solution is that I can do this one by one.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in batch? If not, is it possible to create a new report using the SDK and the RDL file? If so, I will code an app to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDK to create reports. Have a look at sample code on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309505.aspx). It creates new report record and publishes it for use. All entities involved in report storage are described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334227.aspx).

In CRM 2011 you can use `DownloadReportDefinitionRequest` to get actual rdl file - maybe it is also available in 3.0, so you can fully automate transfer.